# SQL Server. Запрос на выбор одинаковых строк

Tags: sql, sql-server

Я создал запрос, который, по идее, должен выводить одинаковые записи:

```
SELECT        Преподаватель, Группа, Дисциплина, ВидЗанятий, COUNT(*) AS Expr1
FROM            dbo.Нагрузка
WHERE         (ВидЗанятий LIKE 'Лаб') AND (Дисциплина LIKE '%п/г%')
GROUP BY      Преподаватель, Группа, Дисциплина, ВидЗанятий
HAVING        (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Вот что он выводит:

Т.е. можно заметить, что, к примеру, для первого преподавателя вторую и третью запись он вывел верно, а вот первая здесь ни к чему. Так же со вторым преподавателем: т.к. группы разные, он не должен был выводится.

Т.о. вопрос: как исправить запрос, чтобы он выводил только те записи, где преподаватель один, группа и дисциплина(с точностью до "п/г") тоже одна?

Comment: ну дак все он вам правильно вывел...прям как вы и пишите...все записи чем-то отличаются...а "правильно" - это как? дайте пример входящих/выходящих данных

Comment: и не понятно `..а вот первая здесь ни к чему..` почему не к чему?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц потому что мне нужно выявлять записи, где за разными подгруппами одной дисциплины закреплён один преподаватель, а дисциплина в первой строке другая и причем одна

Comment: ну тогда не группируйте по дисциплине, и покажите толькко те, у которых группа повторяется больше 1 раза

Comment: Просто дополните вопрос примером входных данных. И сделайте это пожалуйста текстом, а не картинкой(выходные тоже лучше в текст превращать).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понял:

что-то типа дампа:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `disc` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `name`, `group`,`disc`,`type`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Кур В.В.','ПЗ-11/12', 'Физика, п/г 1', 'лаб'),
  ('2', 'Кур В.В.','ПЗ-11/12', 'Физика, п/г 2', 'лаб'),
  ('3', 'Зубр В.В.','вн-12/12', 'Реакт, п/г 1', 'лаб'),
  ('4', 'Зубр В.В.','вн-12/12', 'Реакт, п/г 2', 'лаб'),
  ('5', 'Нойз Б.Б.','вк-1/12', 'Лаз', 'лаб'),
  ('6', 'Вор Г.Д.','вс-11/12', 'Заза', 'лаб');
```

ну и результаты:

```
select * from docs
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SUBSTRING ... **для MySQl**
для MS SQL что-то вроде

`SUBSTRING(a.disc, 1, CHARINDEX(',', a.disc)-1)`

```
SELECT a.name as ФИО, a.group as Группа, SUBSTRING(a.disc, 1, INSTR(a.disc, ',')-1) as Дисциплина, a.type as Тип
FROM `docs` a
GROUP BY a.group,a.name
having Count(*) > 1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]